# SqlCommand Create Database race condition in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, microsoft-sync-framework, sqlcommand

If I create a database and then try to connect to it with MS Sync Framework within 2 seconds it throw Exception "Cannot open database ..."

Adding

```
Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

Will cause code to work properly, however I don't want a hard time set as this code will be running on tablets and other weak hardware, so the time to generate the database could differ drastically.

I can check if database exists after creation and it always does right away, so conditional waiting(spinning) isn't an option.

```
using (SqlConnection masterConnection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString)) {
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{0}') CREATE DATABASE {0}", databaseName), masterConnection)) {
        masterConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

bool databaseExist = false;
while (!databaseExist) {
    using (SqlConnection masterConnection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString)) {
        using (SqlCommand verifySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{0}'", databaseName), masterConnection)) {
            masterConnection.Open();
            databaseExist = (int)verifySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() > 0; // Always true
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
...
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlSyncScopeProvisioning = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnection); // throw ("Cannot open database") db doesn't exist 
}
```

Issue seems to be with the SqlConnection, the first SqlConnection can see the database exists, but the second(new one) can't see it exists for those first few seconds (fails on SqlConnection.Open()).

**Stack Trace**

```
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncUtil.TryOpenConnection(IDbConnection connection)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncUtil.OpenConnection(IDbConnection connection)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlEditionHelper.GetEdition(SqlConnection connection)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning.set_Connection(SqlConnection value)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning..ctor(SqlConnection connection, DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDescription, SqlSyncScopeProvisioningType provisioningType, Boolean expectConnection)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.SqlSyncScopeProvisioning..ctor(SqlConnection connection)
```

**Mark II based on @CharlieBrown's answer**

The code @CharlieBrown posted does work by itself, but not in the setting I have, the following code demonstrates the crash. If you uncomment the manual throw then the code will work properly, otherwise not.

```
try {
    //If I manually throw this exception then code in catch will run fine, otherwise not.
    //throw new Exception("Cannot open database testDB"); 
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlSyncScopeProvisioning = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnection); // throw ("Cannot open database") db doesn't exist 
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    if (exception.Message.StartsWith("Cannot open database")) { // Database does not exist, try to create
        try {
            using (var masterConnection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString)) {
                using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{0}') CREATE DATABASE {0}", databaseName), masterConnection)) {
                    masterConnection.Open();
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlSyncScopeProvisioning = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnection); // throw ("Cannot open database") db doesn't exist 
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { // Always end up here
            // ex = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "testDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user ...
        }
    } else { // Other exception
        // Never hit
    }
}
```

**Edits**

Updated code per using suggestions, added stack trace.
Added another code example to demonstrate issue.

**Solution**

After talking to @CharlieBrown there doesn't seem to be a solution to this issue, so I will work around it by always running the SqlCommand to create database if not exist, rather than trying to use database and then creating in catch() if exception. This code is only run on app start.

Comment: I think you may be missing a question here...

Comment: How can I get the code to work/access database properly right away without sleeping.

Comment: Or intelligently spin/wait for it. ex. While(not Exist) {sleep()}

Comment: My suggestion would be what you just mentioned; use a `while` loop to see if the database exists and if it does, connect to it.

Comment: But doing that says the database does exist if using the same connection. I'll try checking if it exists on the second connection.

Comment: sqlConnection.Open(); fails on second connection within those first 4 seconds.

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Your call to `SqlSyncScopeProvisioning` is being called before SQL Server has a moment to get the database ready for Synchronization. I can't find a reference for the amount of time offhand, but after the database is created, several triggers occur to ready the database.</strike>

Working code:
Tested against LocalDb, Sql Server 2008r2, Sql Server 2012

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;";
var databaseName = "TestRepl";

using (var masterConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{0}') CREATE DATABASE {0}", databaseName), masterConnection)) {
        masterConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

var syncConnectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True;", databaseName);
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(syncConnectionString)){
    SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlSyncScopeProvisioning = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnection); // throw ("Cannot open database") db doesn't exist 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried resetting those after creation, but doesn't help with this issue. I didn't show that code above to simplify amount of code.

Comment: @Charlie -The provisioning is the part that prepares the database for synchronization, not the database creation

Comment: @JuneT Correct. I am talking about the time it takes before the database can be provisioned. I will update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: @CharlieBrown after the edit your code nicely demonstrates the issue, what does that code answer though?

Comment: @Brent on my machine, it works without throwing an exception.

Comment: @CharlieBrown hmm that code does work on its own. I'll poke around and see if I can figure out why not working in my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieBrown the code runs fine in that setting, but if running that code because connection failed once (in catch) then it won't work. I added the code to demonstrate that to my question.

Comment: @Brent why would you throw an exception? We should continue this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

---

After reading your question again, I noticed you utilized `SqlSyncScopeProvisioning` which is an *Asynchronous* operation.  Your database though created, is more then likely finalizing provisioning- but since it is *Asynchronous* it returns before it has finalized.  So the next command triggers because it isn't finished yet.

Which more then likely doesn't have an allocated completion time.

Also you should really be utilizing the `using command`.  It implements the `IDisposable` which will help dispose of *memory allocation* which will help with resource management.

Please keep in mind with the implementation of raw SQL in the manner above, it can be susceptible to *SQL Injection*.

You may want to follow Scott Chamberlain's advice, make usage of `parameters`.

```
private static void CreateSQLDatabase(string dbName)
{
     string createDb = "CREATE DATABASE @DatabaseName";
     using(SqlCommand buildSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(createDb, connectionForSql))
     {
          buildSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DatabaseName", dbName);
          connectionForSQL.Open();
          buildSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

You'll also want to ensure that the database doesn't exist before creation, you may also want to check that it indeed successfully create and provision before continuing.

**Important: "Can be susceptible to SQL Injection" Below**

```
using(SqlConnection connectionForSQL = new SqlConnection(@"Server=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Database=master"))
{
     string verifyQuery = string.Format("SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE NAME = '{0}'", dbName);
     using(SqlCommand verifySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(verifyQuery, connectionForSQL))
     {
        connectionForSQL.Open();
        int databaseId = (int)verifySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        return databaseId > 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: He should be using `using` but you really should be using parameters (and so should he).

Comment: Actually isn't working currently, I can call IsDatabaseInExistence it will return true, I can wait 1000 ms and still opening connection will fail if I don't wait longer.

Comment: Greg, your CreateSQLDatabase method is open to Sql Injection, which is what @ScottChamberlain is pointing out.

Comment: @abhi actually you can't use parameters for `CreateSQLDatabase`, `CREATE DATABASE @DatabaseName` does not work. I was talking about `IsDatabaseInExistence`. But yea, Greg go check to see if the database `'; EXEC sp_MSForeachdb 'DROP DATABASE [?]'; --` exists.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Really?  Okay, I'll make those changes then to the code to reflect if the parameter doesn't work to create a database.

Comment: @Greg syncronisity of SqlSyncScopeProvisioning  isn't an issue because it will crash (Database doesn't exist) on constructor, even if I call it 5 times in a row after the IsDatabaseInExistence returns true and waiting a short time.
Thanks for the using suggestion, and SQL injection isn't an issue in this context but I'll likely change the code to counter it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am able to inject a drop database command in this code.
http://pastebin.com/brEXdH0d

Comment: @greg - SqlSyncScopeProvisioning is not async. Likewise, the actual provisioning occurs when you call Apply().

Comment: @JuneT I think my wording is poor, I meant the functionality of the `SqlSyncScopeProvisioning` acts like an `async` because as part of the first synchronization session, the client database is prepared for synchronization, and all rows are downloaded to the client database as incremental inserts. So it takes time for the database to prepare.

Comment: The code above is not even provisioning yet. Provisioning starts when you call Apply(). There is no provisioning or synchronization happening yet.